# Android Soft keyboard doesn't get the focus

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm working on an android Toshiba TV application. There is a EditBox. When I move cursor there, the soft keyboard is not shown until I press OK. However the focus is never moved to the soft keyboard so that I can't select any letter on it. My same application works on other TV. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Hey dude, did you found any solution to this?? I'm working on a project and i need to set the focus on any letter of the keyboard to use the D-PAD from my control. My project works well on some devices, but doesn't work on others.